# Table not created in mysql from hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Table is not being created in database using hibernate. I am not able to figure out what is wrong in the configuration. I have posted the error trace i get and all of my classes/configuration below.

**Error trace:**

```
Jun 30, 2014 12:47:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myServlet] in context with path [/springMVC] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'jh.user' doesn't exist] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'jh.user' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2643)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2362)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:631)
    at interfaceImpl.UserImpl.addUser(UserImpl.java:33)
    at controllers.UserController.addUser(UserController.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**My model class:**

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String userType;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

}
```

**My hibernate config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jh</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hmb2ddl.auto">create</property> 
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="models.User" /> 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**My implementation code:**

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    User resultUser= (User) session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: why do you think it should be created?

Comment: can u please point out where i am wrong. I am new to hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate's purpose is mapping your classes to a set of tables in the database, it doesnt create them for you, you have to create them manually.

Comment: hmb2ddl.auto -> hbm2ddl.auto, typo. Very informed comments by the way, you clearly have worked with Hibernate for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-misc-properties 
suggests it should be hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

so just correct your  `<property name="hmb2ddl.auto">create</property>`  line

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you mentioned `hmb2ddl.auto` instead of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` also it has spelling mistake.

so change it to `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Answer (score 0):

You should not user reserved keyword of database. like user

user one of the property

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

and change your table name from user to something else my_user, user_model, test_user.

user is reserved keyword so it can be problem. If you try to run create query generated by hibernate displayed in console you will see that it's not executed properly

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<property name="hmb2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

to

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```